# Django uwsgi import error

Tags: django, import, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

I have a Django project with one app called `subscribe`. In root `urls.py` I use include from `subscribe`'s `urls.py`.

I put to `INSTALLED_APPS` `subscribe` and in `subscribe`'s `urls.py` I use `subscribe.views.<name>` for call my views. When server run as `python manage.py runserver` locally all works fine. But when server run on nginx+uwsgi with virtualenv, I've got `ImportError: No module named subscribe`. 
When I changing `subscribe` to `project.subscribe` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and in `subscribe`'s `urls.py` changing `subscribe.views.<name>` to `project.subscribe.views.<name>` all works fine.

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi] 
socket = 127.0.0.1:9003 
workers = 2 
master = true 
virtualenv = /home/user/python 
chdir = /home/user 
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings 
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
daemonize = /home/user/uwsgi.log
```

Why should I use absolute path import and how I can change it to relative back on nginx+uwsgi with virtualenv?

Comment: add `project` to your python path either through the virtualenv startup script or otherwise

Comment: my startup script already include it:

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/project')

Comment: Django threats folders with __init__.py as packages and you set up `/home/user/project` as root directory at your `wsgi` script, so it should be working just as `python manage.py runserver` works.

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta yes, all directory project and all subdirectories have an __init__.py file, but if I change 'project.subscribe' to 'subscribe' in my installed apps, I get an import error.

Comment: Could you provide uwsgi configs?

Comment: @SuperDuper, sure:    

    [uwsgi]  
    socket = 127.0.0.1:9003  
    workers = 2  
    master = true  
    virtualenv = /home/user/python  
    chdir = /home/user  
    env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings  
    module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()  
    daemonize = /home/user/uwsgi.log

Comment: I don't understand, how use markdown in comments :(

Comment: @ZedXter, try to add pythonpath=/path/where/lives/settings.py/ to your uwsgi config

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your uwsgi config should include `pythonpath=/path/where/lives/settings.py/` directive, so python interpreter will know where to find your apps.

Find more information about uwsgi config options:

- http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc
- http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example

Comment: After spending countless hours trying to figure this out, the wording of your answer helped. Thanks a lot :)